# How to socialize GWT application?

Tags: gwt, twitter, facebook, linkedin-api

I am developing a GWT application that displays services provided by a company and I must allow users to share links of services in social networks like Facebook, LinkedIn and Twitter.
Have you any idea how to do such a thing?
Any help is appreciated
Thank you in advance for your help :)

Edit

i have tried AddThis but nothing was displayed
there is the code :

```
    HTML socialNetworkLink = new HTML(
            "<div class=\"addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style\">"
                    + "<a class=\"addthis_button_preferred_1\"></a>"
                    + "<a class=\"addthis_button_preferred_2\"></a>"
                    + "<a class=\"addthis_button_preferred_3\"></a>"
                    + "<a class=\"addthis_button_preferred_4\"></a>"
                    + "<a class=\"addthis_button_compact\"></a>"
                    + "<a class=\"addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style\"></a>"
                    + "</div>"
                    + "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var addthis_config = {\"data_track_clickback\":true};</script>"
                    + "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-4dd380ca4d8393c9\"></script>");
    sharePanel.add(socialNetworkLink);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use content sharing tools like [addthis.com](http://www.addthis.com/).

**EDITED:** or [sharethis.com](http://sharethis.com/)

Comment: I copy the code in my gwt page using HTML component but nothing is displayed

Comment: did you follow instructions? Or maybe share some code?
**Edit:** I've tried script of addthis.com in [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and it works!

Comment: are you getting any error couse i have tried script and it worked. Use firebug.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter: http://twitter.com/about/resources/tweetbutton
Facebook: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
LinkedIn: http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1075

So where's the problem?

Comment: the problem with the solution you offer me is the customization of the description, picture and title to share eg facebook must define it as properties in <meta> what I can not do with gwt since pages are generated automatically by the compiler.

Comment: AFAIK Facebook is the only one of these 3 where you have to specify OG-Tags (and you don't even MUST do this). You should edit your question, so everybody knows what you're talking about and **what your problem is**